# I am Facing issue in Hueman theme Menu Behind the div

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am facing an issue in customizing the hueman WordPress theme. My Dropdown menu content is showing behind the top title h2.My web site is [wortlo.com](https://wortlo.com/)

I tried to fix this with the following rule:

```
overflow:visible!important
```

I wish my dropdown menu can show over every other content

Comment: You should increase the `z-index` of the `#header` element, but doing so you'll need to adjust also paddings and margins of many other elements, because the template was constructed using negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

Your header has `1` Z-index. Increase it To give it more priority.
You can do it by adding following code as [Custom CSS in Customizer](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/).

```
#header {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Resource: **[Css z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)**

UPDATE: The header has padding in bottom so increasing z-index will hide your title. So remove padding. And your Container has negative margin so removing header's padding will hide the title. Remove margin of #page.container to adjust it.

```
#header {
    z-index: 999;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#page.container {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```